# How to persist a webservice reference instance in an SQLCLR stored procedure?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sqlclr

At the moment I have a windows service written in C# that waits for a message in SQL Server Service Broker, and upon receipt calls a webservice method with details passed in the message.

I want to replace this with an SQLCLR stored procedure that calls the webservice directly, which I've found to be quite simple. I can then call this using internal activation.

However it needs to create a new instance of the webservice for each method, and from experience I've found this takes some time. In the windows service I create it with lazy instantiation in a static class, but I understand static fields can't be used to store information in SQLCLR.

Is there a way to persist this webservice reference?

*Edit:* Here is the lazy instantation code referencing the singleton I'd like to persist:

```
static class WsSingleton
{
    static MWs.MWS mWS = null;

    public static MWs.MWS GetMWS()
    {
        if (mWS == null)
        {
            mWS = new MWs.MWS();
            mWS.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("user", "password", "domain");
        }
        return mWS;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this helpful? http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/using-static-properties-in-sqlclr-udts.aspx

Comment: @AdamHouldsworth I did see that article before posting, it clarified the limitation, but gave no solution.

Comment: The solution it gives is to make the reference a static readonly, which is not writable after initialization so satisfies SQL's issues with it.

Comment: You're right it may have solved the problem, but Remus has put me off trying it out.

Comment: Yeah no problem, I posted it as a comment for your information, I wasn't convinced it was a solution myself so I didn't post an answer. Remus's advice seems sound.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> > it needs to create a new instance of the webservice for each method

Do you mean the client has to instantiate a proxy for each HTTP call it makes? If that's what you mean you shouldn't have to persist any reference. An internal activated procedure is launched when there are messages to process and it can stay active and running. Such a locl state could be the proxy instance used to place the WWW calls. Typically the procedure runs a loop and keeps state on the stack as local variables of loop method. See [Writing Service Broker Procedures](http://rusanu.com/2006/10/16/writing-service-broker-procedures/) for more details. To be more precise, your code should not `RECEIVE` *one* message at a time, but a set of messages.

But I would advise against doing what you're doing. First and foremost, making HTTP calls from SQLCLR is a bad idea. Doing *any* sort of blocking in SQLCLR is bad, and doing blocking on waiting for bits to respond from the intertubez is particularly bad. The internal SQL Server resources, specially [workers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187024.aspx), are far too valuable and few to waste them waiting for some WWW service to respond. I would advise keeping things like they are now, namely have hte HTTP call occur from an *external* process.

A second comment I have is that you may be better of using a table as a queue. See [Using tables as Queues](http://rusanu.com/2010/03/26/using-tables-as-queues/). One typical problem with queueing HTTP calls is that the WWW is very unreliable and you have to account for timeouts and retries. Using a table as a quueu can achieve this easier than a true Service Broker Queue. With SSB you'd have to rely on [conversation timers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187804.aspx) for reliable retries, and it makes your activation logic significantly more complicated.

Comment: +1. Nice article on using tables as queues. How would you add notifications or pendable dequeing to that idea, so the dequeue process doesn't have to rely on polling? The ability to have multiple pending readers is one of the reasons I tend to use Service Broker for queuing -- but it's certainly a headache to set up, so if there's an easier way....

Comment: @RickNZ SSB has indeed the ace of non-pooling RECEIVE, and activation as bonus. There isn't anything that can replace *that*. But if your queue is busy enough, then you can get away with polling. I implemented a system just like OPs using a table based queue, and dequeueing a large batch of 100 WWW calls, then dispatching them async using [BeginGetResponse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.begingetresponse.aspx). It works quite well and was able to achieve very high throughput. All as an external, dedicated, C# process.

Comment: @RemusRusanu Not sure if it's the proxy, I've added the instantiation code that I'd like to persist to clarify. But your 2nd para has put me off this course. I might investigate external activation rather than a constantly waiting windows service. My volumes aren't high enough for polling a table queue.